# Ubuntu boot problem, failed to send h2c command

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, boot-repair

I don't know why and how did this happened, I'm using ubuntu 20.04, installed it just a week ago, everything was fine and all until today when I rebooted it showed this: [image]

I reinstalled the whole ubuntu just because of this error and it is still there. It's stuck here and is not booting now. I am new to ubuntu and don't know much about grub. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer Your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217892/system-responds-with-failed-to-send-h2c-command-on-shutdown-what-does-that-me

Comment: yeah, I did go through it previously, they mentioned that it's a bug but what to do with that? I am new to ubuntu, I didn't understand much. And also the error didn't occur today, I was able to boot, I don't know what's happening.